# Unity new Input System, detect which key was pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game i have six spells. I don't want to create an action for each spell to activate it.
With the old input system I would have created a class with an attribute that specifies which button should be clicked.
Like this.

```
public class SpellInput : MonoBehavior 

[SerializeField]
KeyCode key;

private void Update()
{
   if(Input.GetKeyDown(key))
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

With the new input system I really don't know how to do it. With 6 different actions I should create 6 different classes because the method name will be different for each action. Some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exactly mimic the old behavior without creating an action map, or additional classes.

Expose an `InputAction` and check for `triggered` in `Update`.
You can also bind to the `performed` event of the `InputAction` to avoid using `Update`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class SpellInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private InputAction action;

    private void Start()
    {
        action.Enable();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (action.triggered)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Action triggered!");
        }
    }
}
```